# jQuery datepicker multi-month mode duplicate weeks

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I want modify jQuery datepicker for not duplicate days from other month in some else month in multi-month mode (see image below, I want to remove red-marked days). Can you help me?

[image]

As you ask, this is my code for calendar:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var weeks = new Array();

    function inWeeks(startDate) {
        for (var i in weeks) {
            if (weeks[i].getTime() == startDate.getTime()) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    function removeWeek(startDate) {
        for (var i in weeks) {
            if (weeks[i].getTime() == startDate.getTime()) {
                weeks.splice(i, 1);
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    function addWeek(startDate) {
        weeks.push(startDate);
    }

    var selectCurrentWeek = function() {
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            $('.week-picker').find('.ui-datepicker-current-day a').addClass('ui-state-active')
        }, 1);
    }

    $('.week-picker').datepicker( {
        numberOfMonths: 2,
        showOtherMonths: true,
        selectOtherMonths: true,
        hideIfNoPrevNext: true,
        firstDay: 1,
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { 
            var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
            var startDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - date.getDay() + 1);
            //var endDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - date.getDay() + 6);

            if (inWeeks(startDate)) {
                removeWeek(startDate);
            } else {
                addWeek(startDate);
            }

            selectCurrentWeek();
        },
        beforeShowDay: function(date) {
            var cssClass = '';
            for (var i in weeks) {
                var startDate = weeks[i];
                var endDate = new Date(startDate.getFullYear(), startDate.getMonth(), startDate.getDate() - startDate.getDay() + 7);
                if(date >= startDate && date <= endDate)
                    cssClass = 'ui-datepicker-selected-week-day';
            }
            return [true, cssClass];
        },
        onChangeMonthYear: function(year, month, inst) {
            selectCurrentWeek();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: What datepicker are you using? What does your code look like?

Comment: Standard jQuery datepicker (jquery-1.6.2, jquery-ui-1.8.14.custom)

Comment: As @AndrewWhitaker says, we would need you to post a bit of your code. What you want to do works perfectly fine on jQuery's demo page... http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#multiple-calendars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get rid of those two lines :

```
showOtherMonths: true,
selectOtherMonths: true,
```

The option showOtherMonths "Display dates in other months (non-selectable) at the start or end of the current month" and the selectOtherMonths "When true days in other months shown before or after the current month are selectable."